# Elements of an AC expression

Tags: voltage, ac

I am doing some coursework and research on AC theory and currently exploring the below expression:

$$V= 100sin(100\pi t) + 60sin(300 \pi t - \pi/2) + 30sin(600 \pi t + \pi/2)$$

I need to find the:

- Amplitude of Fundamental
- Frequency of Fundamental
- Amplitude of Harmonic components
- The Phase Angle
- The Instantaneous Value of v 5.12 ms from the start of cycle.

Now, I have looked on line and everything seems over ambiguous from my Text book on Engineering science and to be honest has made me even more confused.

Now my understanding of this expression is that it represents 3 waves? Thus, I am assume then I can/will have to be broken up in sections to achieve each answer.

Comment: The fundamental is usually the lowest frequency.  Harmonics are some multiple of the fundamental frequency.  (The 2nd harmonic would have twice the frequency of the fundamental.)

Comment: Ok, so to clarify 100, 60 30?

Comment: No, more than likely the amplitude referred to is RMS not peak.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am not expecting this to be done for me just need some help getting a 'process' together

Comment: OK, try this.  Let \$v(t) = A \sin \left(2\pi f t + \phi \right)\$.  Can you identify the amplitude, frequency, and phase?

Comment: ?!?! Ok so ASIN = Amplitude, F= frequency and 0 = angle?

Comment: The amplitude is \$A\$ - (\$\sin\$ is a function with amplitude equal to 1) - and yes, the frequency is \$f\$ and the phase is \$\phi\$.  So, if \$v(t) = 100 \sin \left(100 \pi t \right)\$, what are the amplitude, frequency and phase?

Comment: 1/50 sin(100 x pi x t) ???

Comment: im stuck :-( !!

Comment: 100 sin(2/Pi x 50 x 5.12ms + pi/2)?

Comment: Grin, being stuck is what learning is all about.  I'm a physicist so I always write my sine waves as A*sin(w*t) where w is omega and has units of radians per second.  EE's may use A*sin(2*pi*f*t), where f is in cycles per second.

Answer (score 1):

The expression says that this signal has three frequency components in it (50, 150 and 300Hz).

The fundamental frequency of this signal is given by the GCD of the frequency components in it (50Hz).

Harmonic components are the components whose frequencies are integer multiples of fundamental. (We have 3rd and 6th harmonic frequencies present in the signal here)

The instantaneous value of `V` can be obtained by substituting the given value (5.12ms) for `t` in the expression.